# divide one column by another column's previous value

Tags: r

```
column a   column b
 10          2
 30          3
 40          4
```

in r, how can i divide column B's value by previous row value of column A

like 3/10 and 4/30

Comment: Could you please reformat your code to make a more readable?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 3):

Using Base R:

```
 transform(dat,new=c(NA,head(column_a,-1))/column_b)
  column_a column_b      new
1       10        2       NA
2       30        3 3.333333
3       40        4 7.500000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()` and `lag()`from `dplyr`, which finds the next or previous value in a vector:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a = c(10, 30, 40),
                 b = c(2, 3, 4))
```

First option: `lead()`

```
lead(df$b) / df$a
```

returns

```
[1] 0.3000000 0.1333333        NA
```

Second option: `lag()`

```
df$b / lag(df$a)
```

returns

```
[1]        NA 0.3000000 0.1333333
```

Answer (score 0):

like this,

```
dta <- data.frame(column_a = c(10, 30, 40), column_b = c(2, 3, 4))
# install.packages(c("tidyverse""), dependencies = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)    
tbl <- dta %>% as_tibble() 
mutate(tbl, column_a_lag = lag(column_a), a_lag_div_b = column_a_lag/column_b)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   column_a column_b column_a_lag a_lag_div_b
#>      <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1       10        2           NA          NA
#> 2       30        3           10    3.333333
#> 3       40        4           30    7.500000
```

obliviously, you can also go there *directly* by,

```
tbl  %>% mutate(lag_a = lag(column_a)/column_b, lead_b = column_a/lead(column_b))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   column_a column_b    lag_a   lead_b
#>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1       10        2       NA 3.333333
#> 2       30        3 3.333333 7.500000
#> 3       40        4 7.500000       NA
```

I want to echo Sotos' comment above. It's generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it. In addition, you should always strive to rovide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. I will also recommend to take a look at this post; [*how do I ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), but since you are new to the site we try to help you getting started.

Answer (score 0):

Using data.table

```
 dt[ , new:= column_b /  shift(column_a)]

  column_a column_b       new
1:       10        2        NA
2:       30        3 0.3000000
3:       40        4 0.1333333
```